# why does assigning to pointer result in panic

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
type box struct {
    val int
}

var p *box
```

This works fine:

```
p = &box{val: 2}
```

But this results in error:

```
*p = box{val: 2}
```

Error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference 
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x5e59d9]
```

Why does the 2nd form of assignment result in panic?

Comment: `*p = ` tells Go to mutate the thing `p` is pointing to... but `p` isn't pointing to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `p` points to nothing (`nil`). You must first allocate some memory and make `p` point to it before being allowed to deference `p`. You can use the [`new`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Allocation) builtin to allocate memory initialised to the zero value of the pointed type.

```
p = &box{val: 2}
```

has the same result as:

```
p = new(box)
*p = box{val: 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the pointer is not pointing anything. It's value is null. If it pointed to something, then you could try to change the thing which is being pointed at.

```
p = &box{val: 2}
```

Before this statement, p = nil, after this statement, p = some memory address.

```
*p = box{val: 2}
```

Before this statement, if p = nil, you'll get an error, because you're trying to set value, of address which is stored in variable p. It basically tries to get something from nil address.

If you did that:

```
p = &box{val: 2}
*p = some new value
```

It would work fine, because p already points to some address and you can change value on that address.

Comment: maybe I am tainted by C background, where `p` would be a variable that initially pointed to `nil` and i am simply making it point to a different address. it seems Go has it a little different.